# Python: Setting Multiple Attributes for a file (e.g. System, Hidden)

Tags: python, attributes, file-attributes, bitflags

What is the way to set multiple file-attributes using Python?

E.g. I want to set a file's attribute to System, Hidden.

I can use something like below, but it will just set just one attributes, and overwrite the previous write:

```
import win32con, win32api, os

filename = "some file name"

win32api.SetFileAttributes(filename,win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
win32api.SetFileAttributes(filename,win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```

This will end up with just Hidden attribute.

How do you set both attributes at once? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here is the solution.  I made it generic for general use.

```
import win32api
## If need to install pywin if not already to get win32api

## Define constants for Windows file attributes
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = 0x01
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = 0x02
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = 0x04
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x10
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = 0x20
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = 0x0100

## Combine all the attributes you want using bitwise-Or (using the pipe symbol)
Attribute = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM

filename="Your-filename-goes-here"

win32api.SetFileAttributes(filename,Attribute)

## Check that the attribute is set.
## You can also right click on the file in windows explorer and 
## look under Details tab.

print win32api.GetFileAttributes(filename)
```

Comment: Well, some attributes were missing for me: https://rokdd.xyz/tech/on-demand-files-in-python-reading-file-attributes-in-windows/